# How can I have private videos (on a private Pro Vimeo profile) viewable and DOWNLOADABLE on my website?

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins, vimeo

(Using Wordpress plugins and **Vimeo API**)

I have had a bespoke Wordpress plugin built and am struggling now with one capability.

I have paid for a Pro Vimeo account so that I have better privacy options, but I need to have the videos viewable and most importantly DOWNLOADABLE  on my client's website.

I am sure this was possible before, but after three software developers have tried and mostly not managed to complete my job briefs, I am left pretty desperately on how to finish this key functionality.

When I try to download the videos straight from the website, it won't let me and takes me to a blank page. The only way to fix it is to make my Vimeo profile and videos public on Vimeo however, it is vital that they are private on there.

I would be SO GRATEFUL if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the API to retrieve file download links for your videos.

Make an authenticated request to https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id] using a token with the `video_files` scope. In the response is an array `"download"` that will contain video file metadata, including download links, and the expiration time of those links.

Comment: Ok so I did with another download script but unfortunately, it would not work either. So I have done a lot of blog reading and I got results that Vimeo won't allow an audience to download private videos with ANY script.
Vimeo has blocked the API method for Private videos that's why it's not working.

Is there any chance of this changing? I have upgraded to a PRO Vimeo account for the supposed advanced privacy features, yee this has been a waste of time and money...

Comment: We are doing the same as you have written about @tommypenner - we also got the id & its format as well. But it would not work.... Please help!

Comment: I have made a separate question which may be clearer to readers, please check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020754/vimeo-privacy-settings-affects-inhibits-download-functionality-when-embedded-on