# Vimeo privacy settings affects/inhibits download functionality when embedded on a website

Tags: vimeo

**Vimeo states:** "Hide this video from Vimeo" will make the video unable to be accessed on the Vimeo website (unless you are logged in as yourself), but it still can be embedded on other websites. Your video can be added to albums and portfolios, but no other types of collections."

In the Vimeo settings, with 'Hide from Vimeo' selected, there is also a checkbox titled 'What can people do with your videos?' I have 'Download them' selected.

So, as far as I am aware, the Vimeo videos should be able to be embedded on my client's website, 'hidden on Vimeo' yet still 'downloadable' from my client's website.

This is not the case. We can not download from the client's website unless the Vimeo settings are set to 'Public,'

Vimeo actually inhibits the download functionality when privacy settings "Who can watch your videos?" are set to anything other than "Anyone." So you have to have public videos on Vimeo which defeats the object of paying for PRO.

**The scenario:** *My client has sensitive videos which they use Vimeo to host (privately). These videos are streamed to private client pages on the Wordpress website using a bespoke plugin. Only the people with access to the private client area on the website should have access to these videos and they must be private everywhere else on the web. BUT, they must be downloadable from the client area.*

Please help! We have spent two months developing a bespoke WordPress plugin and now this error is occurring.

We are using Vimeo PRO.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The "download" option in the video's settings refer to the Download button that appears on the video page at vimeo.com/[video_id]. That download setting has no bearing on its ability to be downloaded using the download link; the download link should work anywhere its served, provided that the link has not expired.

See the "Download videos" Help Center article here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229678128-Downloading-videos

There are only two supported methods to serve a download link on your website:

- Use the Vimeo API to retrieve the download link from Vimeo:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009156/3704546
- Get the download links from the video's distribution settings page:
  https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links

These are the only supported methods to get download links; if you're using another method to get download links, the links may expire or break at any time.

Comment: thank you - I think we cracked it with a new script!